# Is it shirk to call someone lord/god/goddess as a show of respect?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

For example, let's say I had a friend who is really good at fighting (or any sort of combat). If I say that he is "a god of war" as a show of respect, is that shirk? I'm not actually saying that he's God, I'm just emphasizing how good he is at fighting.

Another example, if a muslim man was trying to appreciate the beauty of his wife so he calls her a "goddess of beauty", is he committing shirk? Or if he said something like "She is my goddess" just to emphasize how much he respects her, is that shirk?

Also, in medieval England, some high ranking people used to be called "Lord". Is that shirk?

Comment: It probably depends on your intention. When you call your friend "God of War" you don't actually believe he is a deity that deserves worshiping, right ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm not saying he is an actual god. I'm just saying he's a very good fighter.

Comment: As @SpiderRico mentioned, I'd say it depends on the intention. The word "rabb" for instance, which normally is translated to "Lord" is for instance used by Prophet Yousef: { إنَّهُ رَبّـي أحْسَنَ مَثْوَايَ } يقول: إن صاحبك وزوجك سيدي

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not permissible to call someone a “god”, “goddess” or “lord”. Because, this would lead you to commit shirk, and you will be punished very sever by God Almighty.

Here is how and why it is haram to respect someone by saying “god” or “goddess” to this person.

> Umar ibn Al-Khattab reported: The Messenger of God, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Do not exaggerate my praises as the Christians have done with the son of Mary. Verily, I am only a servant, so refer to me as the servant of God and his messenger.”

---

> They have certainly disbelieved who say, “God is the Messiah, the son of Mary” while the Messiah has said, “O Children of Israel, worship God, my Lord and your Lord.” Indeed, he who associates others with God – God has forbidden him Paradise, and his refuge is the Fire. And there are not for the wrongdoers any helpers.”
>   **[Sural Ma’idah, Al-Qur’an 5:72]**

So this means, that if you do call someone as goddess as a respect, then you do same as the Christians do. And God Says:

> ”Whoever dies associating anything or anybody with Me, then he/ she will drive you to Hell and you shall stay there forever and ever.”

And here it means, that if you do call someone as god or goddess, then you have committed shirk and it is to be punished.

> ”Verily, I am God! None has the right to be worshipped but I, so worship Me, and perform al-Salaah [prayer] for My Remembrance.” **[Ta-Ha 20:14]**

This means, you can respect only your Lord by saying God, bow to Him and worship Him alone, only to Him you can worship, and no one else.

And also, God Almighty Says:

> Say, "He is God , [who is] One,
>   God , the Eternal Refuge.
>   He neither begets nor is born,
>   Nor is there to Him any equivalent." **[Surah al Iklaas]**

So here it means, that God has no gender, but if you call someone “goddess” or “god”, then you have committed a disbelief because, you have added a gender to God, and that is not correct at all.

You can call “lord” as long as you don’t associate with Lord God, the Lord of the worlds. If you say: “I am your Lord” with capital “L”, then you have committed shirk, and if day with with small letter “l” such as: “I am your lord”, then it is ok to use it. But the word “lord” it is a noble rank used by usually by Britains.

**Conclusion:** you cannot say to this person as a respect you look like a “goddess” or “god” because it is shirk, and shirk is unforgivable sin, and it is an exaggeration. If you want to respect someone say: “masha’Allah” or “wow, you are a good person” or “may God reward you with good” and so on. But, do not bow to someone other than God as a form of respect, because it is a major sin, and you can only bow to one God, the Creator, who is your Lord, the one who Made you.

Hope it helps.

And God knows best.

Comment: As far as I know, in literary Arabic (The quran language) you can say "the God of the house", to mean the man of the house, or you can say "the God of the sheep", to mean the owner of a sheep. so i think when you say the God of war, and your intention is to mean that a person is good at fighting, you can say it, as long as you don't associate his level with Allah all mighty level.

Comment: @Diptox I think you're correct.

Answer (score -2):

This is shirk! Dont ever call anyone but ALLAH by ALLAH's names or attributes.

If your friend is good at something like basketball or tennis ect. say MashALLAH TabarakALLAH, you are very good at playing ball ect.

And ALLAH knows best.

My ALLAH save us against shirk. amin

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on answering the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Actually in Islam there is difference between God and Allah. Allah is the only God for pray, but God is a general word. And if you use it in the meaning of God it's not shirk but it's better to don't use it. if you use it in the meaning of Allah it is completely Shirk.

Comment: Can you prove any evidence for that?